# Is it possible to add an action for certain keywords in a search bar in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have hundreds of keywords that I want to perform a certain action with when a user searches it in the search bar. Is there any way to do this for a wordpress site using PHP? If so how would I edit the search results php file to not display the list of results but instead perform the action.

For example, user types "blue" into the WP search bar and hits "search". Instead of a page of search results they are taken to paint.com/blue.

Then for certain other keywords they are taken to a page on the current website. For example, user types "green" into the WP search bar and hits "search" and are taken to the [www.mywebsite.com/green](http://www.mywebsite.com/green) which is a page on my wordpress.

This I know will have to be a huge IF statement for each keyword, I am guessing.

Comment: An alternative to if statements could be an array. keyword as index, url as value. Then you only have to check for the presence of keyword.

Comment: @RST how would that work? thank you for replying

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to a long if else sequence could look like this:

```
<?php

$myWords = [
    "phrase1" => "redirect1",
    "phrase2" => "redirect2",
    "phrase3" => "redirect3",
    "phrase4" => "redirect4",
    ];
    
$location = (array_key_exists(<searchword>, $myWords)) ? $myWords[<searchWord>] : false;

if ($location) {
  header("Location: $location");
  exit;
}
             
<default search continues here>
?>
```

You may need to adjust it a bit to meet your needs.